# SQL request with JOIN and COUNT

Tags: sql, join, count

I can't make a database query, as in this picture:

[image]

Here is the database schema:

```
CREATE Table Ages (
    id integer primary key,
    Period varchar(10)
);
INSERT INTO Ages VALUES (1, '0-1'), (2, '1-2'), (3, '2-3');
CREATE TABLE Toys (
    id integer primary key,
    age_id integer foreign key references Ages (id)
);
INSERT INTO Toys VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 1);
CREATE TABLE ToysUsers (
    id integer primary key,
    uid integer,
    tid integer foreign key references Toys (id)
);
INSERT INTO ToysUsers VALUES (1,1,1);
```

I am trying to create the `Result` view from the picture with something like this:

```
SELECT 
    toys_age_groups.id, toys_age_groups.period, 
    COUNT(t3.age_id) as co
FROM 
    toys_age_groups 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         t1.id, t1.age_id 
     FROM 
         `toys_toys` t1 
     LEFT JOIN
         toys_user_toys t2 ON t2.tid = t1.id 
     WHERE
         t2.id = ?) AS t3 ON toys_age_groups.id = t3.age_id 
GROUP BY 
    period 
ORDER BY
    id ASC
```

Comment: That's too bad. What have you tried?

Comment: Can you explain what you have to do?

Comment: add my sql request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading your question right, the result table give you the age ID and Period, and then the count of toys per age ID and Period. Here is how you would write that query:

```
SELECT Ages.ID, Ages.Period, IFNULL(sub.cnt,0) AS Count
FROM Ages LEFT JOIN
(SELECT Toys.age_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Toys
GROUP BY Toys.age_id) sub
ON Ages.ID = sub.age_id
```

Comment: need exclude by custom toys_users.uid (variable) from toys where toys.id = toys_users.tid

Answer (score 0):

Ty kbball!

Just update ur script

```
SELECT 
    Ages.ID, Ages.period, IFNULL(sub.cnt,0)
AS 
    Count
FROM 
    Ages 
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        Toys.age_id,UserToys.uid , COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM 
        Toys
    LEFT JOIN
        UserToys
    ON 
        UserToys.tid = Toys.id
    WHERE 
        UserToys.uid <> 1
    OR 
        UserToys.uid IS NULL
    GROUP BY 
        Toys.age_id
    ) sub
ON 
    Ages.id = sub.age_id
```